# How does Arbib's clustering method work?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, image-segmentation

Recently in Image Processing I've been studying image clustering (or segmentation) methods and one of them is [Color Image Segmentation Using Competitive Learning](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/387488). I understand the main idea behind it from which you start with one cluster with its cluster representative then pixel values get assigned to this cluster (also involving a learning rate, what is it?) until you reach a certain amount and the cluster gets cloned, the algorithm stops when you reach the desired amount of clusters.

I searched for quite a while on the internet but i didn't find anything about this method, can you please explain to me precisely how the algorithm works, how pixel values get assigned, what is the learning rate (it might be called in the different way because i'm translating from my language), what are the input and output and all the steps of the algorithm?

Comment: I think it's all described in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.6282&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Hi Matt I tried opening it with Explorer , Firefox and Chrome but failed in all of them. Explorer tells me it's a damaged file while on the other two they jut stop loading the file half way through, isn't there any other link where i can find this paper?
Thank you

Comment: The site seems to be down right now. Try later, it worked half an hour ago.